# StackoverflowException only in release-mode?

Tags: winforms, wcf, visual-studio-2010, release-mode, debug-mode

I installed VS2010 on Windows server 2008 R2 and started a Winforms app that makes an asynchronous WCF call for a rather big object graph (~25 Mb in XML) to services deployed on another machine.

When I start in debug-mode in VS2010 (debug->start new instance) it works fine.

When I start in release-mode in VS2010 (debug->start new instance) it crashes with a soft stackoverflow exception, I have no callstack but I suspect the deserialisation of underlying XML.

Any ideas how this may occur?

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing the maximum message size buffers in the WCF config file.